# Birt: prevent repeat DataSet execution were used in multiple tables in report

Tags: dataset, birt, multiple-tables

I have a Birt report that has 3 Tables, each presenting a different summary of a single "Data Set". Unfortunately Birt is generating the "Data Set" 3 times. Is there anyway to convince BIRT to reused a "Data Set" instead of regenerating the DataSet for each Table in the report.

The DataSet is Scripted Data Set implemented using a Java Event Handler class. and is not configured with any parameters or filters.

This problem is significant for this report because the "Data Set" can contain over 1 Million rows. I This means the report is spending 3 times longer collecting the data than it should.

I hoping the solution may also reduce the size of the pre-rendering "rptdocument" (pre-rendered document) which is currently 1.6GB.

I hoping the a solution will not required me to manually cache the rows of the dataset against the report execution context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the data set to a grid on top of your report
you have to give that grid an unique elment name

for your three tables you can switch in the Propert Editor -> Binding  from Data: (the data set) to Report Item (choose the unique elmenet name of the grid)

after makeing this changes the dataset is executed only once and reused in all three tables